# Spring boot, Tomcat unable to recognize JSF bean

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, jsf

I am trying to run Spring Boot + JSF application with `mvn spring-boot:run` while my project works perfectly when deployed on Payara, on Spring Boot Tomcat it looks like its unable to recognize JSF beans.

Error code

```
Sun Dec 16 22:33:33 CET 2018
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
/hello.xhtml @14,48 value="#{helloBean.name}": Target Unreachable, identifier [helloBean] resolved to null
```

I am aware that in my example I am using JSF 2.2, but at first I tried different versions of code and pom, but I was unable to get it working, after few hours I deployed it on payara and it was working so now I am trying to figure out what is wrong with my example that I am unable to run it with Tomcat on Spring boot, that is why I used such simple example below.

Here is my code

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>adsad</groupId>
<artifactId>adasdsad</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath />
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.17</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.17</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>



</project>
```

Application.java

```
package hello;

import com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener;
import org.h2.server.web.WebServlet;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.*;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.*;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletListenerRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.context.ServletContextAware;

import javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application implements ServletContextAware {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}

@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean facesServletRegistration() {
    ServletRegistrationBean registration = new ServletRegistrationBean(
            new FacesServlet(), "*.xhtml");
    registration.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    return registration;
}

@Override
public void setServletContext(ServletContext servletContext) {
    servletContext.setInitParameter("com.sun.faces.forceLoadConfiguration", Boolean.TRUE.toString());
}

@Bean
public ServletListenerRegistrationBean<ConfigureListener> jsfConfigureListener() {
    return new ServletListenerRegistrationBean<ConfigureListener>(
            new ConfigureListener());
}


}
```

HelloBean.java

```
package hello;


import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import java.io.Serializable;

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class HelloBean implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private String name;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
}
```

hello.xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">

<h:head>
    <title>JSF 2.0 Hello World</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h2>JSF 2.0 Hello World Example - hello.xhtml</h2>
    <h:form>
    <h:inputText value="#{helloBean.name}"></h:inputText>
    <h:commandButton value="Welcome Me" action="welcome"></h:commandButton>
</h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

welcome.xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">

<h:head>
    <title>JSF 2.0 Hello World</title>
</h:head>
<h:body bgcolor="white">
    <h2>JSF 2.0 Hello World Example - welcome.xhtml</h2>
    <h2>Welcome #{helloBean.name}</h2>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: yoiu need a web.xml or faces-config.xml if you are with jsf 2.2 : her you can check some simillar configuration : https://dzone.com/articles/developing-jsf-applications-with-spring-boot   or   https://www.beyondjava.net/jsf-2-2-primefaces-5-spring-boot

Comment: Thanks, but my code works on Payara, beans are recognized, it looks like my configuration is somehow not correct for tomcat. If I understand correctly then faces-config.xml and web.xml are not required in >JSF 2.0

Comment: @x0x0, were you able to resolve this? I am also getting same issue as mentioned at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72811623/spring-boot-2-7-1-integration-with-jsf-2-2-mojarra-and-primefaces-6-2-9